# Error showing while creating new project in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

[image]

Why this error showing while trying to serve(run) a new project in AngularJs ?
Node is installed.
Angular CLI is installed.
A new project is created.

Comment: Is your project name Angular or you need to navigate inside this folder? it clearly says there is no `package.json` file

Comment: Please show the directory. `dir` + enter

Comment: Clearly you don't have a project to serve. `ng new <projectname>` then `cd <projectname>` and finally `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing something here .

If you are using cli you need to first install cli using `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then

- ng new PROJECT-NAME
- cd PROJECT-NAME
- ng serve

If you are just forking a angular library please check if any package,json file is there in the  root or any level if it is there navigate to that folder and then do a `npm install`

Comment: But "ng serve" command is not working well. That's shown in the screenshot!